# How to create an exe file for Flask Python app

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, py2exe, py2app

I am using following dependencies

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import webbrowser
```

I want to create an executable file. My file structure is as follow

Main_Folder

- app.py
- database.xlsx
- template

------- Templates.html

- Static

-------- Files.png

Can it be done in a way thay Flask Static and template files as well as the data files are still available to the execuatable file.

Comment: Pythion 3 with py2exe and py2app? They arn't compatable with Python 3 try [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) or [Cx_Freeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/)